# Get all JIRA issues that have been worked on in the last X hours

Tags: jira, jql

I need a JQL query, that shows me all issues, that have been worked in since X hours.

I can find in JIRA, to get all resolved issues in the last X hours `resolved >= '-1h'` or created `created >= '-1h'`, but don't find any to get those, that have been started to work on.

So there is the status field, that switches from "OPEN" to "IN PROGRESS", which is the progress I'm interested in.

I tried `updated >= '-1h' AND status in('IN PROGRESS') AND status was in('OPEN')`, but the `status was` does not take the `updated` into account, which means, I do also get an issue back, that has been updated with something in the last hour, but the status change was done way longer ago.

So how can I get the issues, that had the status change in the last X hours ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the *CHANGED* operator. Its documentation is available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-operators-reference-764478341.html#Advancedsearching-operatorsreference-CHANGEDCHANGED).

You can use a query like:

```
status changed TO "In Progress" AFTER -4h
```